# How can I set redis Sessions to expire automatically on browser close in laravel 4

Tags: php, session, redis, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 with a Redis-session.
I need my session to expire automatically when I close my browser window.

When using native sessions, that works by setting the session lifetime to `0`
When using redis session, that doesn't work, because then my sessions expires immediately

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: And what happened with redis-session if you set lifetime to 0? What is the expire time of session cookie?

Comment: Laravel uses the Redis cache driver for redis-sessions, so a hacky solution could be an `onbeforeunload` ajax request, that calls `forget` on the redis driver, to destroy the session. Personally, though, I'd use the `session.cache_expire` setting, and forgive me for saying this, but a session that is always destroyed when the client disconnects seems odd. I'd like a session to persist, so that next time I visit your site, I can pick up where I left

Comment: @klipach when I set lifetime to `0` the cookie sets the expiration time to `session` which is good, but redis expires all data immediately after it saves it, because of the `lifetime=0`. I use `redis-cli monitor` and see all the data persisted to redis, but then it is immediately expired

Comment: I posted an issue on github, I think it would be good if you could set the lifetime of the redis-records independantly from the lifetime of the cookie